# Using gRPC with Vert.x, netty dependency issue

Tags: java, server, netty, vert.x, grpc

I am trying to add a gRPC to one of our vert.x servers and running into some issues. Has anyone else tried running gRPC alongside vert.x? The first issue I am running into is due to a netty dependency version mismatch: Vert.x wants to use netty 4.0, while gRPC needs netty 4.1.

Specifically, the issue I am running into is when netty 4.1.0-Beta5 is used I get a AbstractMethodError on a call to org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.AssembledFullHttpRequest.touch because that method is not implemented. AssembledFullHttpRequest implements the ReferenceCounted interface that netty provides, which added a touch method between versions 4.0 and 4.1.

Any advice would be appreciated.

I have also posted this question to the gRPC and Vert.x google groups.

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

I think there is currently no way to run it together due version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

There is now official `gRPC` support for vert.x see [vertx-grpc](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-grpc).

The project also provides a custom [compiler](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-grpc-java-compiler) plugin to provide vertx-y API's instead of the general java ones.

And the simple [manual](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-grpc/java/).